# como hacer que el valor por default del ng-options se quede seleccionado

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Tengo el siguiente caso al usar `ng-options` en mi dropdownlist.

Este es mi html:

```
<div class="col col50 colmin">
    <div class="pull">
        <div>{{selectIdCuenta.nombreAlias}}</div>
            <select name="ifield06" ng-model="selectIdCuenta" ng-change="getListRecibos()" ng-options="cuentas.nombreAlias for cuentas in listCuentasCoorporativas">
                <option value="">Cuenta</option>
            </select>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

y este es mi controller que llena el select:

```
  productoServicio.getCuentasCoorporativos().then(function(response) {
      $scope.listCuentasCoorporativas = response.data.obtenerListadoMovilCorporativoCuentaResponse.listadoCuenta;
      angular.forEach($scope.listCuentasCoorporativas, function(val, key) {
          if (val.idCuenta == idCuentaCoor) {
              $scope.selectIdCuenta = $scope.listCuentasCoorporativas[key];
          }
      });
   }, function(error) {
      $scope.status = 'El cliente no cuenta con Lineas Moviles Coorporativas: ' + error.message;
   });
```

lo cual funciona bien al renderizar y se selecciona correctamente el `$scope.selectIdCuenta` pero al darle en el valor `"Cuenta"` el dropdown se muestra vacío y no carga el valor `"Cuenta"`.

Estoy controlando que no haga nada si selecciona ese valor pero necesito que se muestre el valor por default `"Cuenta"` del HTML.

Por favor alguna ayuda o guía 
Saludos

Adicionalmente el array que obtengo (Json) es de la siguiente manera:

```
{   
    "listadoCuenta": [{
        "idCuenta": "1000.123.67",
        "nombreCuenta": "Principal",
        "aliasCuenta": "Padre",
        "nombreAlias": "Padre"
    }, {
        "idCuenta": "1000.543.1",
        "nombreCuenta": "Principal",
        "aliasCuenta": "Padre",
        "nombreAlias": "Cta Nueva"
    }, {
        "idCuenta": "5.4300.12",
        "nombreCuenta": "Principal",
        "aliasCuenta": "Padre",
        "nombreAlias": "Cta Otros"
    }]
}
```

Comment: El json no se corresponde con lo que tienes en la vista(`nombreAlias` -> `aliasCuenta`). Quizas estas cambiando la colección en `getListRecibos()` ya que yo reproduje el código que pusiste y funciona como se espera. Que debería hacer la aplicación al seleccionar el valor `"Cuenta"`

Comment: Bueno tienes razon al Json le falto el dato de nombreAlias, pero agregandole ese dato, me sigue fallando, estoy viendo que cuando selecciono algun dato del array listCuentasCoorporativas el Div <div>{{selectIdCuenta.nombreAlias}}</div> se carga con el dato seleccionado y cuando selecciono el valor por default "Cuenta" el Div <div>"Vacio"</div> queda vacio. no se porque? alguna ayuda?

Answer (score 3):

El valor se esta seleccionando correctamente, lo que pasa es que angular es *noble* y a diferencia de JavaScript no lanza errores cuando haces binding a una propiedad que da `null` o `undefined`. Esto por supuesto sólo aplica a la vista y no al código JavaScript.

Por ejemplo puedes haces esto

```
$scope.test = {};
```

y en la vista puedes tener esto

```
{{test.foo.bar}}
```

En JavaScript hubiera lanzado un error inmediatamente ya que esto le esta diciendo que acceda a la propiedad `foo` del objeto y que en esta acceda a la propiedad `bar`. En este caso `foo` es `undefined` y te hubiera dado el error.

> Cannot access property `bar` of `undefined`

```js
var test = {};

console.log(test.foo.bar);
```

En angular no ocurre así

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('TestCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.test = {};

    $scope.nullable = null;
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="TestCtrl">
  Aqui debería ir el contenido {{test.foo.bar}} {{nullable}}
</div>
```

En ese caso en particular `ng-options` le dará el valor `null` a tu variable y por lo tanto no saldrá contenido.

Ya que este es el comportamiento esperado de angular si quieres que te muestre algo puedes crear un filtro que te muestre un texto en caso que el valor recibido sea `undefined`

Este es un ejemplo usando un filtro `unselected`

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('CuentasCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.listCuentasCoorporativas = [{
      "idCuenta": "1000.123.67",
      "nombreCuenta": "Principal",
      "aliasCuenta": "Padre",
      "nombreAlias": "Padre"
    }, {
      "idCuenta": "1000.543.1",
      "nombreCuenta": "Principal",
      "aliasCuenta": "Padre",
      "nombreAlias": "Cta Nueva"
    }, {
      "idCuenta": "5.4300.12",
      "nombreCuenta": "Principal",
      "aliasCuenta": "Padre",
      "nombreAlias": "Cta Otros"
    }];

    $scope.muestraDatos = function() {
      console.log($scope.selectIdCuenta);
    }
  })
  .filter('unselected', function() {
    return function(input) {
      return input === undefined ? 'No seleccionado' : input;
    };
  });
```

```css
select {
  border: solid 1px gray;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="CuentasCtrl">
  <div>{{selectIdCuenta.nombreAlias | unselected}}</div>
  <select name="ifield06" ng-model="selectIdCuenta" ng-change="muestraDatos()" ng-options="cuentas.nombreAlias for cuentas in listCuentasCoorporativas">
    <option value="">Cuenta</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Como puedes ver el ni el binding ni la lógica se alteran ya que los filtros solo modifican el valor mostrado en la vista.

También puedes usar una expresión pero ten cuidado con esto pues si por ejemplo usas `false` o `0` como valor de alguna de tus opciones te puede fallar.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('CuentasCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.listCuentasCoorporativas = [{
      "idCuenta": "1000.123.67",
      "nombreCuenta": "Principal",
      "aliasCuenta": "Padre",
      "nombreAlias": "Padre"
    }, {
      "idCuenta": "1000.543.1",
      "nombreCuenta": "Principal",
      "aliasCuenta": "Padre",
      "nombreAlias": "Cta Nueva"
    }, {
      "idCuenta": "5.4300.12",
      "nombreCuenta": "Principal",
      "aliasCuenta": "Padre",
      "nombreAlias": "Cta Otros"
    }];

    $scope.muestraDatos = function() {
      console.log($scope.selectIdCuenta);
    }
  });
```

```css
select {
  border: solid 1px gray;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="CuentasCtrl">
  <h3>Con el operador ||</h3>
  <div>{{selectIdCuenta.nombreAlias || 'No seleccionado'}}</div>
  <select name="ifield06" ng-model="selectIdCuenta" ng-change="muestraDatos()" ng-options="cuentas.nombreAlias for cuentas in listCuentasCoorporativas">
    <option value="">Cuenta</option>
  </select>
  <h3>Con el operador ?</h3>
  <!-- Esta version es un poco fea-->
  <div>{{selectIdCuenta.nombreAlias === null || selectIdCuenta.nombreAlias === undefined ? 'No seleccionado' : selectIdCuenta.nombreAlias}}</div>
  <select name="ifield06" ng-model="selectIdCuenta" ng-change="muestraDatos()" ng-options="cuentas.nombreAlias for cuentas in listCuentasCoorporativas">
    <option value="">Cuenta</option>
  </select>
</div>
```